# how to alter entity reference field (taxonomies) field options in hook form alter

Tags: forms, hooks, 9

Can anyone please let me how to alter entity reference field (taxonomies)
field options in hook form alter,

Seems the below code doesn't work.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_article_edit_form' || $form_id == 'node_article_add_form') {
    $channel_options = [
      '1' => 'Term1',
      '2' => 'Term2',
      '3' => 'Term3',
      '4' => 'Term4',
      '5' => 'Term5',
    ];

    $form['field_channel'] = [
      '#title' => 'Channels',
      '#description' => 'Select Channel',
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => $channel_options,
    ];
  }

}
```

**For context :**

I have a field named as channels in node article which is entity reference to channel taxonomy.

I would like to limit the list of terms visible to current user to the channels to which they are assigned in their user profile.

I am trying to achieve it by altering the node edit form and replacing channels field values from the current user logged in.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but there is an alternative, no-code solution for this: With views module, create a view of taxonomy terms. Filter that view as required (in your case most likely a contextual filter on the current user). As display plugin for that view select "entity reference". Then on node field settings, select "Views: Filter by an entity reference view" as "Reference method".

Comment: Thanks Hudri let me try that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Hudri suggestion. I am able to achieve it without code using views module.

I followed the guide from [How to Use Entity Reference Views in Drupal 8 - OsTraining](https://ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-8-entity-reference-view/) and created a contextual filter to filter by current logged in user.

The important thing here is define Configure contextual filter When the filter value is NOT available.

[image: View settings]

[image: View Contextual Filter Settings]

[image: Node Field Channel]

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/47544262/6687229